# A paladin player immediately identified a disguised/polymorphed NPC in Tomb of Annihilation

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, tomb-of-annihilation

...and I'm not sure how to react to it now.

This is during the Tomb of Annihilation campaign, while recruting a Guide, this player used his *Divine Sense* around

> **Eku**, a polymorhed [Couatl](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/couatl).

He immediately went to talk to her, and told her he knew she was a disguised celestial thing, and started asking question like "Why are you here?", "Which god do you serve?", "Can you help us?", ...

This is not too hard to handle, and I think I've managed it well, but my issue is if they choose to hire *that character*.

I usually like to create light Character sheets, and give them to the players so they can control the NPCs in their group freely as long as it is not in opposition to the NPC's alignment/background. But *that character* is very powerful and have Innate Spellcasting and all, so I want to handle it this way:

***That character* pretends to be a human (very good) spellcaster to anyone except the paladin but asks for his discretion. If the player characters prove themselves to be trustworthy, *that character* will tell them the truth and help them find**

> Omu

I think I will give the players this statblock, and let them play *that character*:

> [image: Stat Block]

**Do you think it's a good idea? Am I taking the risk that *that character* will be too powerful and help the party so much that their own characters will not be as useful as *that character*?**

Comment: Dear jbuiss0n, welcome to the Stack. While we handle a lot of questions, there is something we are very bad at: handling "Should I" questions that ask for an advice about a situation, as these are highly opinion based. We can answer you what the DMG says about such a situation or if a specific set of powers together breaks the game rules or is more powerful than a typical baseline power set, maybe even dig in our deep chests for sage advice how to handle a problematic player or two, but we can't (and won't) tell you what to do. As the question stands, we voted to close as opinion based...

Comment: ...BUT that does not mean the question is not answerable at all! What we need of you is in many cases more information. In this case, I would like to see what **you** think to do. An alternative, which might be even better would be to ask about the possible impact that revealing the true form might have on the adventure. That might help you make your choice easier. A slight side note from a fellow GM that is not to be taken as an answer in any way though: **You are the GM** - do what you believe/know/suspect is the most fun for you and your players!

Comment: The use of "them"/"they" is clearly to hide the identity of the character in question, but unfortunately it makes the post a little confusing when you start using "they" to refer to the party as well. I'd suggest using something like "that guide" or "that character" instead for clarity. (Also, "there own characters" should be "their own characters", in the end of the question.)

Comment: I am confused how the paladin even knows it's a celestial, considering Eku would have the shielded mind trait all couatls have.

Comment: Shielded mind doesn't prevent a divine sense, _The couatl is immune to scrying and to any effect that would sense its emotions, read its thoughts, or
detect its location._

Comment: So... the paladin sensed a celestial within 60 feet without knowing their location, in a crowded city, and instantly came to the conclusion that it's the guide?

Comment: Nah, they were in a Tavern, looking for a Guide, they were getting introduction to candidates -and Eku (the Couatl) is one of them-, and the Paladin _(a suspicious guy, he knows me too well...)_ uses his **Divine Sense**, just in case. The Couatl was almost standing in front of him...

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely up to a DM as to how to handle NPCs. You certainly don't need to give the PCs control over them if you don't want to.

It is also entirely up to a DM as to how an NPC reacts, what questions they are willing to answer and so on.

Even a celestial isn't necessarily going to drop everything just to help the PCs - it may have its own inscrutable reasons for being mysterious! E.g. it may know that the PCs must brave some dangers and get some experience (in the game-sense, not a meta-sense) before they will be capable of handling a more dangerous threat later and therefore drop hints to this effect.

Comment: I agree, and share you opinion on the DM doing as he want to. My question is more about the Tomb of Annihilation campaign itself, and how to handle this tricky hireable guide (especially now that is she not more undercover), without spoiling the whole plot and doing too much on behalf of the characters, who are a lot weaker for now.

Comment: Did you already give too much away, or can you instead make her appear as a weaker NPC initially? Perhaps she is still suspicious of the motives of the PCs, and does not reveal her true powers _just_ yet, instead feigning being weaker (and if she or they ever get into real trouble maybe then she can reveal who she really is)?